# how to fix Error: element-wise multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions

Tags: r, regression, data-modeling

I am building geographically weighted Poisson Regression in r. I was stuck in bandwidth selection part, having `Error: element-wise multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 116x5 and 251x5`.
I tried reducing rows 251*5 matrix, and in this cases 116*5 matrix was also reducing at the same time.Anyone can help me ? Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Hi. You are more likely to get a useful answer if you include a reproducible example, including all library calls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example provides guidance. (ps please don't add images of code or data : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).